# MVC3 DropDownList and ViewBag. How add new items to collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, viewbag

I got a little problem with ViewBag and DropDownListFor. Code below Working fine but i need add 'by hand' one item with value 0. Any ideas how i can do this ?

```
public ActionResult Create()
{

            ViewBag.ParagrafyRodzic = paragrafRepository.All;

            return View();
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ParagrafID, ((IEnumerable<Projekty03.Models.Paragraf>)ViewBag.ParagrafyRodzic)
.Select(option => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = option.ParagrafNazwa.ToString(),
    Value = option.ParagrafID.ToString(),
    Selected = (Model != null) && (option.ParagrafID == Model.ParagrafParent)
}),Translate.ChooseList)
```

:) Tx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a static method for building the SelectList. Somewhere in the model put something like:

```
public static SelectList MakeSelectListDipendenze(SomeCollectionColl, bool emptyElem = true)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> Items = new List<SelectListItem>();
            if (emptyElem)
                Items.Add((new SelectListItem { Text = " ", Value = "-1" }));
            foreach (ElemInCollection Item in Coll)
            {
                SelectListItem AddMe = new SelectListItem();
                AddMe.Text = Item.Description;
                AddMe.Value = Item.Id.ToString();
                Items.Add(AddMe);
            }
            SelectList Res = new SelectList(Items, "Value", "Text");
            return Res;
        }
```

In your wiew you refer to this via

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Field, ModelClass.MakeSelectListUtenti(Model.Destinations), new { id="Destinations"})
```

Comment: Tx BigMike, that's was exactly what i need :)